# How to validate(assert) that the default value selected in a combo box is correct

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I have a UI,for which I need to perform some tests. I have a testcase that has to verify the default value selected in a combo box. I have been using coded UI, and tried to reverse code. But the statement, *Assert.IsTrue(comboBox.SelectedItem == Value)* doesnot work. When I looked into the UIMap code, the SelectedItem property is defined in another class. I don't understand how I can implement it. It would be great help, if I could get some suggestions. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `Assert.IsTrue` is the best method to choose.

You could try:

```
Assert.AreEqual(comboBox.SelectedItem, Value);
```